# Not able to set each texture mipmap level manually

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures

I'm not able to manually set the mipmap levels in opengl. This doesn't throw an error but no texture is displayed. Uncommenting glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D) works (means it works the mipmap levels aren't set by me).

My mipmap levels seem to be complete as the last level (12) is a 1x1 image.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string texture_levels[]) 
: m_FilePath(texture_levels[0]), m_LocalBuffer(nullptr), m_Width(0), m_Height(0), m_BPP(0)
{

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    GLCall(glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE\_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE\_2D, G_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 12));

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        m_LocalBuffer = stbi_load(texture_levels[i].c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 4);
            GLCall(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, GL_RGBA8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_LocalBuffer));
    }

    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));

    // glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
    if (m_LocalBuffer)
            stbi_image_free(m_LocalBuffer);
}


Texture::~Texture()
{
    GLCall(glDeleteTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Bind(unsigned int slot) const
{
    GLCall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot));
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Unbind()
{
    GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
}
```

In Main.cpp:

```
std::string texture_levels[] =
{
    "res/textures/istanbul/01.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/02.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/03.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/04.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/05.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/06.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/07.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/08.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/09.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/10.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/11.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/12.png",
    "res/textures/istanbul/13.png"
};



Texture texture(texture_levels);
texture.Bind();
```

Comment: Note, the size of the a level has to be half of the previous level rounded down. See [Mipmap completeness](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_completeness).

Comment: @Rabbid76, thank you so much. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a mitmap at a level has to be half of the size of the previous level, rounded down. 
See [Mipmap completeness](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_completeness).

More concretely, the size of a width, height or depth of a mipmap at a level `i` is the integral part of a division of the corresponding size of the texture image by `2^i`. The size of the last mipmap level is 1 for all dimensions, so the number of mipmap levels depends on the size of the texture and is `log2(maxsize) + 1` (truncated), where `maxsize` is the dimesnison of the texture with the greatest size.

Th relevant part in the specification is [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 8.14.3 Mipmapping, page 265](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=287&zoom=100,0,525)